# Run multiple Jmeter scripts in parallel from jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am using `jmeter-maven-plugin` to run jmeter performance scripts. This plugin execute scripts sequentially. However, I wish to run number of scripts in parallel.

I really don't know quite where to start with this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but a workaround.

You can try to merge all your scripts. Put each of them in it's own **Thread Group** in a single .jmx.

Comment: Not possible as the script would go on increasing day by day. @George Rylkov